# Query Exception in Connection.php

Tags: sql, laravel, null

this is my migration code..... or schema you can say

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
      //  $table->string('name');
        $table->string('to');
        $table->string('from');
       // $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the Error is shown up when i run this on laravel :

Comment: Your code is not readable. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: now you can check i think its better now

Comment: When is this error occurring? Give some more detail about the error. Check in your `laravel.log`.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: bro i dont understand what to do in log file i m new to the Laravel and i want to store the data to the database and this error occur i have to update the value in database and fetch it into the laravel panel that is install already

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
  public function up()
{
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('to');
    $table->string('from');
    $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}

 public function down()
 {
  Schema::drop('users');
 }
}
```

try to use this code, 
Also check setting of database related in env file and database.php